# How to change image on click

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

So I want to change an image onClick and change it back oClick. 
This is my current code, but for some reason it doesn't work. I can't find out what's wrong with it.

```
var newsrc = "suspects.png";
var newsrc = "questionmark.png";

function changeImage() {
  if ( newsrc == "suspects.png" ) {
    document.images["img"].src = "/images/suspects.png";
    document.images["img"].alt = "suspects";
    newsrc  = "questionmark.png";

  }; else {
    document.images["img"].src = "/images/questionmark.png";
    document.images["img"].alt = "questionmark";
    newsrc  = "suspects.png";
  };
};
```

I´m pretty sure it´s good like this... Why doesn´t it work?

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon after the closing brace for your `if` block, so that's likely producing a syntax error.  You also try to declare the `newsrc` variable twice, you only need to do that once.

Comment: debugging JS .. fun .. - try loading it into a debug tool (i.e. firefox with firebug) and see if the the JS is bombing out.

Comment: Thanks! it doesn't give an error anymore now, but it still doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Toggle a image only checking the source**

```
function toggle(){
 var img=document.getElementById('img');
 img.src=img.src=='url1'?'url2':'url1';// needs to be the full url.
}
```

**Regarding you code:**

you define `newsrc` 2 times and so the first one is lost.`newsrc` is always "questionmark.png"

```
}; else{
```

should be

```
}else{
```

and

if you have `suspects` set then you want `questionmark` if clicked, and not `suspects`.so invert the `if` content.

should be

> if suspects then questionmark else suspects

you have

> if suspects then suspect else questionmark.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/SLkHu/

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works on jsfiddle and it's bugfree now, but it still doesn't work on the website itself. Any idea why that is?

Comment: are the indispensable variables global?btw what code are you using now ? create a jsfiddle.

Comment: This is what I have now. http://jsfiddle.net/SLkHu/

Comment: I had to delete an use strict

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra semicolons `;` in your code

It should be

```
function changeImage() {

      if ( newsrc == "suspects.png" ) {
        document.images["img"].src = "/images/suspects.png";
        document.images["img"].alt = "suspects";
        newsrc  = "questionmark.png";

      } else {
        document.images["img"].src = "/images/questionmark.png";
        document.images["img"].alt = "questionmark";
        newsrc  = "suspects.png";
      }
    }
```

Comment: the if check should be inverted.

Comment: @cocco Actually, the question is ambiguous, as the OP has not provided enough code/context to give a good answer. I, for one, read `newsrc` as an abbreviation of "new source". Indicating that the click may be setting the value of `newsrc` to one of those two values, which are then checked by `changeImage()`. So the logic would then be "if the new source (`newsrc`) is `suspects.png`, set the image `src` attribute to `/images/suspects.png`". Obviously not a great way to do things, but I don't think that we can assume that the `if` logic is incorrect.

Comment: yeah right... but as it does not work, i guess that this is the most obvious...anyway i mentioned 3 problems in my answer.